# How to add a text with font color to word document using C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a Word document and I want to add some words to the end of it with font color, using C#. Can someone explain how to add content and then format it?

I tried to use the following code but it doesn't work

```
doc1.Words[i].InsertAfter("Text to be added");   
doc1.Words[i].Font.ColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdBlue;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this is using a `Range` object. You have to define a Range, then if what you're adding should not replace what's already in the Range, the Range needs to be "collapsed". (Think of it like making a selection then pressing the right or left arrow key to get a blinking insertion point (cursor)).

Once you have a Range, you can manipulate it as you wish - it will remain stable. Again, sort of like formatting a selection when working as a user.

```
Word.Range rng = doc1.Words[i];
object oCollapseEnd = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
rng.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);
rng.Text = "the new text";
rng.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlue;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it works with me :)